# Select needed column with 'if', 'else' and compare by it

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select like this:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT IF(type=1, price_1, price_2)) as price_column WHERE price_column > 10
```

But getting this error:

```
Unknown column 'price_column' in where clause
```

Any hints?

Comment: where `price_1` and `price_2` are certain columns in the db

Comment: can't use aliases like that. you'd have to wrap the `select *, (select...)` query in another parent query and do the filtering "up there".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly you missing from table, and you can use this:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT IF(type=1, price_1, price_2)) as price_column 
from table_name WHERE (SELECT IF(type=1, price_1, price_2)) > 10
```

Comment: Thanks, adding additional select in where section is excactly what i was need

Answer (score 2):

is it not simpler to do this ?

```
SELECT *, IF ( id = 1, field1,field2) AS new_field
FROM table_a
having new_field > 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
     SELECT *, (SELECT IF(type=1, price_1, price_2)) as price_column
     ) AS Tab1
WHERE price_column > 10
```